# How to add prefixed type into repeating parent node and select all elements for each using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, prefix

I would like to know how we can add prefixed type [xsi:type"..."] to each repeating parent node and select all child node of it. The xml is of soap envelop and the output is modification of the header and body of the envelop.
The sample input xml is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http://Example1.com"
xmlns:ns1="http://Sample1.com">

<soapenv:Header>
    <ns:SessionHeader>
        <ns:Auth>a1b2c4d5</ns:Auth>
    </ns:SessionHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns:Create>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <ns:BankAccount>
            <ns1:AccountNumber>1111</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:BillingState>Texas</ns1:BillingState>
            <ns1:Name>John</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Phone>+1 111</ns1:Phone>
            <ns1:Site>Chicago</ns1:Site>
            <ns1:Website>www.site1.com</ns1:Website>
            .
            .
        </ns:BankAccount>
      <ns:BankAccount>
            <ns1:AccountNumber>222</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:BillingState>Hawai</ns1:BillingState>
            <ns1:Name>Bob</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Phone>+2 222</ns1:Phone>
            <ns1:Site>Canada</ns1:Site>
            <ns1:Website>www.site2.com</ns1:Website>
            .
            .
        </ns:BankAccount>
        .
        .
        . 
    </ns:Create>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The required output xml for the given input xml is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http://Example1.com" 
xmlns:ns1="http://Sample1.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns:SessionHeader>
            <ns:Auth>a1b2c4d5</ns:Auth>
        </ns:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:Create>
           <ns:BankAccount xsi:type="Account" xmlns="http://Example1.com" >
            <ns1:AccountNumber>1111</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:BillingState>Texas</ns1:BillingState>
            <ns1:Name>John</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Phone>+1 111</ns1:Phone>
            <ns1:Site>Chicago</ns1:Site>
            <ns1:Website>www.site1.com</ns1:Website>
              .
              .
          </ns:BankAccount>

          <ns:BankAccount xsi:type="Account" xmlns="http://Example1.com" >
            <ns1:AccountNumber>222</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:BillingState>Hawai</ns1:BillingState>
            <ns1:Name>Bob</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:Phone>+2 222</ns1:Phone>
            <ns1:Site>Canada</ns1:Site>
            <ns1:Website>www.site2.com</ns1:Website>
              .
              .
          </ns:BankAccount>

          .
          .
          .

        </ns:Create>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried with the below mentioned XSL but it is not producing the required result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns="http://Example1.com"
        xmlns:ns1="http://Sample1.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <ns:SessionHeader>
                <ns:Auth>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//ns:Auth"/>
                </ns:Auth>
            </ns:SessionHeader>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns:Create>
                <ns:BankAccount xsi:type="Account" xmlns="http://Example1.com">
                  <xsl:apply-template select="node()"/>
                </ns:BankAccount>
            </ns:Create>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure where I am getting wrong.
Should I need to first get all the parent "BankAccount" node with its element for prefix addition and then build the soap envelope back?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add `xsi:type="Account"` to each of the `ns:BankAccount` elements, use an [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a specialized template for `ns:BankAccount` that copies the content while adding the attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://Example1.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:BankAccount">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">Account</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and tips. I have tried this but I am getting the answer like this:   <ns:BankAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="Account">' which is not the thing I am expecting... I need like this    '<ns:BankAccount xsi:type="Account" xmlns: "http://Example1.com">'